# Ubuntu issues with Maya 2020 installation

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade

I have some problem installing Maya 2020 on Ubuntu 20.04. While Maya installed, there was a problem with the license and upgrade in the console. What is going on? When tries to run Maya won't start. When trying to start from the console with the command:

`/usr/autodesk/maya2020/bin/maya`

I see something like this:

```
A licensing error occurred that Autodesk systems were not able to handle for you. Please contact Autodesk Customer Support for help in resolving this error.
adlsdkAuthorize returned with error code: ADLSDK_STATUS_ADLS_NOT_FOUND
The default location for log files to help diagnose the issue is: /usr/tmp
```

Interestingly, the path `/opt/Autodesk/AdskLicensingService` does not exist!
Even though I did everything they wrote on the Autodesk website! When I wanted to fix it somehow, I damaged something. With `sudo apt-get upgrade` I see something like this (the console will be in Polish):

```
Czytanie list pakietów… Gotowe
Budowanie drzewa zależności
Odczyt informacji o stanie… Gotowe
Należy uruchomić “apt --fix-broken install”, aby je naprawić.
Następujące pakiety mają niespełnione zależności:
libc6 : Poleca: libnss-nis ale nie da się go zainstalować
Poleca: libnss-nisplus ale nie da się go zainstalować
Narusza zależności: libc6:i386 (!= 2.31-9) ale 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 jest zainstalowany
libc6:i386 : Narusza zależności: libc6 (!= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ale 2.31-9 jest zainstalowany
libc6-dbg : Wymaga: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ale 2.31-9 jest zainstalowany
libc6-dev : Wymaga: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ale 2.31-9 jest zainstalowany
libc6-i386 : Wymaga: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ale 2.31-9 jest zainstalowany
E: Niespełnione zależności. Proszę spróbować wykonać “apt --fix-broken install” bez pakietów (lub podać rozwiązanie).
```

I will mention right away that I was doing `apt --fix-broken install` but this message pops up every time. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not do what it says right in your question? Please contact Autodesk Customer Support for help in resolving this error

Comment: Ubuntu is not on the list of supported operating systems for Autodesk Maya 2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the "official" instructions for installing maya on ubuntu is here: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/simplecontent/content/installing-maya-2020-ubuntu.html

considering the path /opt/Autodesk/AdskLicensingService does not exist on your install perhaps the missing steps for you are the following(shamelessly copy pasted)

```
install the licensing packages: adlmapps, adlmflexnetserveripv6, adlmflexnetclient, and adsklicensing.
Verify that the licensing service is running.

    sudo systemctl status adsklicensing

If the licensing service is not running:
 

    Start it using this command:

    /opt/Autodesk/AdskLicensingService --run
    
    Verify again that the service is running.
     
If it is still not running, set up the licensing service manually:

    sudo getent group adsklic &>/dev/null || sudo groupadd adsklic
    sudo id -u adsklic &>/dev/null || sudo useradd -M -r -g adsklic adsklic -d / -s /usr/sbin/nologin  
    sudo ln -sf /opt/Autodesk/AdskLicensing/9.2.1.2399/AdskLicensingService/AdskLicensingService /usr/bin/AdskLicensingService
    sudo mkdir /usr/lib/systemd/system
    sudo cp -f /opt/Autodesk/AdskLicensing/9.2.1.2399/AdskLicensingService/adsklicensing.el7.service /usr/lib/systemd/system/adsklicensing.service
    sudo chmod 644 /usr/lib/systemd/system/adsklicensing.service
    sudo systemctl daemon-reload
    sudo systemctl enable adsklicensing –quiet
    sudo systemctl start adsklicensing
```